# flutter_widget_from_html tags cannot using custom Styles Builder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, dart-html

I am using flutter_widget_from_html: 0.9.0+1. Faced a problem, some widgets do not use customStyleBuilder and do not use TextStyle. Who creates a solution to the problem. Thanks in advance.

Its HTML string doesn`t work`

```
String value1 = '''
<p class=\"\">
  <span style=\"font-family: 'OpenSans-Semibold'; font-size: 56px; line-height: 64px;\">
    Hello World Not Working
  </span>
</p>
```

`But this HTML string is working`

```
String value = '''
<p class=\"\">
   <span style=\"font-family: OpenSans-Semibold; font-size: 56px; line-height: 64px;\">
     <strong>
       Hello World Working
     </strong>
    </span>
</p>''';
```

`Flutter Widget Code`

```
HtmlWidget(
        value,
        textStyle: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'Arial',
          fontSize: 20,
        ),
        customStylesBuilder: (element) {
          return {
            'font-size': '20px',
          };
        },
```

`

**Thanks everyone for the help**

I tried many different solutions but nothing worked. But i need use only flutter_widget_from_html, flutter_html not suitableю